# What does "@+" and "@*" mean in (oracle) SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

i'm trying to make sense out of a sql query. I can' find a reference to it on the internet or the (oracle) syntax documentation other than the possible use of @ to reference foreign tables, which doesn't seem to make sense here and confuses me in regards to the plus.

```
[...]
from sometable 
   left join [...]
where @+sometable.somecolumn
and @+sometable.someothercolumn
and @*
```

Has anyone seen this before or could point me in the right direction?
( the table isn't called @+, i checked that:) )

Comment: Doesn't look like Oracle to me. I hope someone else will recognize it and explain what it means.

Comment: That's invalid in Oracle. Looks like a placeholder that gets replaced by some tool

Comment: Can you please provide more context? There're many tools that implement their own parser to translate placeholders or even custom languages into regular SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by a_horse_with_no_name:
"That's invalid in Oracle. Looks like a placeholder that gets replaced by some tool"
It is in fact replaced by some internal proprietary tool.

Comment: That code does look suspicious though because there is at least variation of the "@" syntax. If you run a query like `select sysdate from dual@some_database;` it will get translated to `SELECT SYSDATE@! FROM "DUAL" "A1"` on the remote server. The `@!` means "run this command on the originating database, not the remote database."